# Unity: Unsharp edges

Tags: unity, graphics, gameobject

I have a Unity Project and somehow the edges of objects in my Scene (Scene view and game view) look like this:

[image]

I think I already had that problem once, but in my recent projects, this didnt happen anymore.

Is there any solution to that?

Comment: Sorry, can you clarify, what would you like your edges to look like instead of this?

Comment: @DMGregory If you soom in a bit, you can see that the edges arent one straight line

Comment: It looks like your model on the right has a taper to it, and the model on the left is rotated relative to the vertical lines of the screen's pixel grid. So, there needs to be a place where this diagonal edge shifts from one vertical column of pixels to an adjacent column, no? Are you looking for anti-aliasing to smooth this transition of diagonal lines across pixel columns?

Comment: @DMGregory If thats the only way to smooth the edges, yes. But does a cube really look like that even without pp effects? Seems a bit bizarre to me.

Comment: Maybe you're just zoomed in more than you're used to. Yes, every diagonal line drawn on the raster grid of a computer monitor ends up following a stairstep pattern, unless anti-aliasing is applied to fuzz-out the steps.

Comment: @DMGregory i made another Project using URP with Fast Aproximate Anti-Aliasing and it looks super smooth! In my other project, it just did not look good

Comment: If you've solved your problem, please consider documenting the steps to solve it as an Answer below to help other users in a similar situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved:

Simple answer: The unsharp edges are normal, but anti-aliasing solves the problem.

Longer answer: In my case, the anti-aliasing still did not manage to make it look good enough. However, I discovered the Universal Render Pipeline, one of the 2 new render pipelines by unity (probably, the High Definition Pipeline would give an even better look).

I made a new URP project and in the settings of my main camera I activated anti-aliasing and set it to Fast-Aproximate-Anti-Aliasing.

Comment: Can you include screenshots to demonstrate the steps and result?